# Share PPTP Connection to local network computers

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras, pptp

How can i share a PPTP Connection to my local network computers using RRAS and Windows Server 2008 ?

Here is the scheme :

Local Network Computers ==> Router (Win2k8) (VPN Connection) ==> Internet ==> PPTP VPN Server

Thanks.

Comment: i've not hand on the PPTP Server. I want to use the VPN connection to this PPTP Server to route my local traffic to internet though the vpn connection.
It already works if i setup the vpn connection on only one computer, but i want to share this connection.

Comment: Ohh! Ok! I follow. In that case, go with what Michael Graff said, and get RRAS to route all traffic over a NAT on the VPN tunnel

Answer (score 1):

Can the router just offer it via NAT?  That would seem to be easiest.

Comment: NAT is only useful if you have one route (i.e. router -> internet). When you are sharing a PPTP you usually have two (internet and the PPTP tunnel). That said, at least it doesn't require the involvement of the other side of the network to make the routes visible over there as well.

Comment: Sure, but natting can generally be done on an outgoing interface as well, and I'd bet there is an option to send all default route traffic out the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection set up in the RRAS as a VPN Connection, or is the VPN connection set up under the "Create a Connection" wizard?

If it's a VPN in the RRAS, then you can tell the server which network(s) are on the other side of that VPN connection, and assuming you have Routing enabled in the RRAS, it will automatically route all the connections over the VPN as required.

This will only work if your subnet on your local network is different to the remote network (e.g. if your network is 192.168.0.x and their network is also 192.168.0.x then it won't work, but if yours is 192.168.0.x and theirs is 172.0.0.x then it will be fine).

Unfortunately I don't have the time to do a how-to, but hopefully this will put you on the right track.

-- Update --

After seeing your comment on the question, I recommend going with what Michael Graff said, and get RRAS to do NAT on the VPN tunnel. This is the easiest way if you're not looking to split your network.